# Importar array de URL externa com PHP

Tags: php, array

Esse link https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ gera uma array, gostaria de importar ela para uma array local, como faço ?

Tentei fazer:

```
$url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/";

function curl_get_contents($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

    $data[] = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$contents = curl_get_contents($url);

echo count($contents); // 1
```

Mas é criado apenas um índice com todas as arrays dentro dele, o resultado é 1, gostaria de manter o número de contagem de $contents para o número de índices da URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse conteúdo está em JSON, faltou você decodificar. Faça assim:

```
$contents = json_decode(curl_get_contents($url));
print_r($contents);
```

Isso vai gerar uma array de objetos. Se precisar de array de arrays (associativas), passe `true` para o decoder no segundo argumento:

```
$contents = json_decode(curl_get_contents($url), true);
```

Comment: Está gerando isso na frente do indice: [0] => stdClass Object, e não consigo usar o array dentro de foreach($contents as $k => $y) { }

Comment: Veja a atualização acima